# Is it possible to load 2 or more languages at the same time in one document using listings.sty?

Tags: listings

Assume in my book I am discussing two (or more) languages, e.g. PSTricks and LaTeX.

Can I load these languages at the same time in my book document such that their keywords get proper markup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=PSTricks,{alsolanguage=[LaTeX]TeX}]
\begin{pspicture}(3,3)
\rput(1.5,1.5){\LaTeX} 
\end{pspicture}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

=> read the documentation